# Today the motel "is"/"was"/"has been"/"will be" managed

Tags: tense, exam-questions

> Today the motel _________ by the members of the same family.

1. a) is managed
2. b) was managed
3. c) has been managed
4. d) will be managed

I think "is managed" is the most acceptable one, but it doesn't sound like it is correct. I know that the answer is not "b" but I'm not sure about the others.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please provide include [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like your thoughts about the problem.

Comment: Answers **b, c, or d** could be "correct" if, for instance, the previous sentence were: _Last week, some strangers took over management._ That is why we need details, @pureipack !

Comment: All four of them are grammatical.

Comment: These kinds of questions are really well suited for HiNative. You might want to check out that app.

Comment: @zagadka314 thanks for the advice. I will search it.

Answer (score 2):

I would choose "A", but the answers are very ambiguous and depend on the context you are looking for.

"A":  Today the hotel is managed by the members of the same family.
(Possible context: the family used to manage it and nowadays, they do too)

"B": Today the hotel was managed by the members of the same family.
(Context: We pulled in even more money today than yesterday, even though it was managed by the members of the same family.)

"C": Today the hotel has been managed by the members of the same family.
(Context: similar to "B" although a stretch -- I would say this is the least correct)

"D": Today the hotel will be managed by the members of the same family.
(Context: Yesterday the members of the family did a good job.  Today they will get to do it again.)

Choice "A" may sound strange to you, but keep in mind that it is referring to "today" as

> "at the present period of time; nowadays." -Oxford Dictionary

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. it looks like an easy question but it's confusing.

Comment: Lol, yeah. Any of them could be correct in the right context. None of them are wrong